# custom field type for ROS msg

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We're trying to read a radar udp packet and one of the data types is of a RadarDetection[] type which is not supported by ROS (because its a custom type) the size of each index is 224 bits, one solution Im thinking of is :

-creating a message that contains int64[4] RadarDetection_custom and then use that message as a field type to represent the RadarDetection type but with 256 bits instead 224

I am not confident that this solution will work and I was wondering if there is a better solution than this

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/298622/custom-field-type-for-ros-msg/) by [mohthepro](https://answers.ros.org/users/36631/mohthepro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-07-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) on 2018-07-25**:
Could you reformat your question with more punctuation and more information about the data you want to send? You should also check your numbers. `int64[3]` would only hold 192 bits, not 256, and where did "215" come from?

**Comment by [mohthepro](https://answers.ros.org/users/36631/mohthepro/) on 2018-07-26**:
Sorry I meant int64[4], and I reformatted the question to make it easier to read, the 215 bits is just the size of the field type that I am receiving from the radar's UDP packets, I dont know why the radar manufacturers made it like so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

An array of `int8` 28 values long will give you 224 bits. This is the usual approach to storing a binary blob such as your `RadarDetection` type. It will be presented as a `boost::array` of `int8_t`, which you can get the raw pointer to and read into your data type. See the [msg data types page](http://wiki.ros.org/msg) for more information.

---

Originally posted by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) with karma: 4203 on 2018-07-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mohthepro](https://answers.ros.org/users/36631/mohthepro/) on 2018-07-26**:
is there any difference between int8[28] and what I suggested with int64[4] other than less wasted space?

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2018-07-26**:
In some ways no. In fact they will probably take exactly the same space in memory due to the way compilers work. However semantically int64 implies a particular encoding that the data probably doesn't have whereas an array of bytes is the standard encoding of raw binary data.

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2018-07-26**:
So it's a convention really but your code will be more meaningful to other developers of you use a buffer of bytes.